# crontab expression to schedule a DAG to run in specific time interval

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a requirement where my DAG has to run every 5 minutes from 5 AM to 6:30 AM. I know how to schedule with crontab it if it is from 5 AM to 6 AM like */5 5-6 * * * but I have to do this for time interval 5 AM to 6:30 AM.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want from 0 to 30 minutes, all you have to do is instead of every minute in the expression change it to 0-30 minutes with every 5 minutes step.

```
0-59/5 5-6 * * *
```

You can refer to https://crontab.guru/ for checking next values also. Since it gives only 5 next values, you can change the step up from 5 to 20 for better clarity.

Comment: this expression runs only from 5 to 5:30. Thank you :)

Comment: Ah you are correct. Works only for 5-5:30 and then 6-6:30. Have updated the cron rule. Please let me know if this works. Thanks

Comment: Yes as we do not have any straight forward solution to this I have already implemented from 5 to 7 as shown. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution should be using two cron schedulers.

```
*/5 6 * * *
0-30/5 6 * * *
```

So you need to duplicate the dag with difference schedulers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just made some changes and this worked for me.
I just gave the schedule_interval as 

    ['*/5 5 * * *','0-30/5 6 * * *'] and this helped.

Comment: I dont know what you did but this wont work. Airflow doesnt support 2 cron expressions in the same DAG.

Comment: Yes this seems to be an issue. Is there a way to combine these schedule intervals? But I don't want to duplicate my dag

Comment: I don't think we have another way to combine both scheduler intervals in 1 DAG. I know duplicate dag is bad, but in this situation it is acceptable.

Comment: @Rajalakshmi I think another solution is to use the scheduler */5 5-6 * * * but with a python branch operator. In this operator, you should check the execution date then if the current time is 6 and the minute is above 30 you should route the task to dummy task. With the solution, you don't need to duplicate the DAG/